ERROR EJECUCIÓN DATASTAGE 11 Fatal Error: waitForWriteSignal(): Premature EOF on node . A file descriptor does not refer to an open file
HOLA A TODOS TENGO UN ERROR AL EJECUTAR UN JOB DASTAGE 11 ME MUESTRA EL SIGUIENTE ERROR.
Fatal Error: waitForWriteSignal(): Premature EOF on node.A file descriptor does not refer to an open file.
LA EJECUCIÓN SE DA EN CUATRO NODOS PARA APROVECHAR EL PARALELISMO DE DATASTAGE
UTILIZO STAGE JOIN PARA CRUZAR DOS TABLAS INFORMXIX UNA CON 36 MILLONRES DE REGISTROS Y OTRA DE 20 MIL REGISTROS.
